# Money transfer from Ethiopia to UK for tution fee payment

Tags: united-kingdom, foreign-exchange, international-transfer

I need to transfer money from Ethiopia to UK (Leeds university account) for my MSC, would you please advise me how can do it ?

Comment: Ask the college, they should mention how they would accept it.

Comment: Be careful here, make sure you are talking to the actual college, get their contact info off their official website.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to ask the College. If they accept Wire Transfer, get the Bank details and ask your bank in Ethiopia to make the international transfer.

If the college asks for a Bankers check or some other form, take these details and ask you Bank in Ethiopia to arrange for same.